# Use Eclipse as GNOME Extension IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gnome, gjs, gnome-shell-extensions

I am trying to develop my own GNOME Extension.
I have read several articles:

- [gnome-shell-extensions-getting-started](http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.fr/2012/09/gnome-shell-extensions-getting-started.html)
- [gnome-whiteboards-hello-ide](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111231428/http://worldofgnome.org/gnome-whiteboards-hello-ide/)

and the official one.

- [StepByStepTutorial#fromScratch-settingUpEclipse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial#fromScratch-settingUpEclipse)

From [wiki.gnome.org](http://wiki.gnome.org):

> It is very helpful to develop using an IDE with JavaScript support. It will help us with code folding, autocompletion, outline, etc.

> GNOME has his own IDE for develop, called Anjuta. The problem is that IDE has some lacks, like autocompletion, code folding, etc. so for me it is better to develop using Eclipse until Anjuta gets to have this kind of features.

> So, we start setting up Eclipse to have JavaScript support.
> Setting up Eclipse

> Install Eclipse from your app store of your distribution. Open Eclipse and select your workspace. Go to "Help". "Install new software". Select Work with "All available sites". Search for JavaScript. Install. That's it!

I manage to use Eclipse to write my first extension, but I would like to enable the code completion feature. I found this feature is an huge help to speed up code writing.

I assume that I have to set correct "Include Path" into my JavaScript project. But I can't find which path I have to add.

Note: I use Eclipse Kepler with JavaScript Development Tools on Fedora 19.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the same stuff, so if you found anything, please share it with us ! Thanks

Comment: Maybe take a look here: `Using JavaScript Content Assist` -> http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm (make sure to check the note at the top that reads: `enable JavaScript Support for the project and Set the JavaScript Build Path` and follow the links there as well.)